# Disable 'disabled' property in jqGrid colmodel

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid and i'm setting a column `disabled` or `enabled` based on some conditions. So i have set property `disabled` to empty or `disabled` based on that condition.

What i'm getting is, in both the cases my column is disabled. So is there any way to disable the disabled property

Something like,

```
disabled=false or readonly=false
```

So that i can set both `true` or `false` based on that condition.

FYI,
I'm setting value like this,

```
editoptions: { defaultValue: this.DefaultValue, disabled: this.IsReadOnly }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All unknown properties of `editoptions` will be interpreted as attributes which values should be set. If you set attribute `disabled` **with any value** it will be interpreted as disabled. Only some versions of web browser required to set the value of `disabled` to `"disabled"` (`disabled="disabled"`). So the usage of `disabled=""` should have the same meaning as `disabled="disabled"` in the most web browsers. Absolutely the same rule have `readonly` attribute.

If you don't want to disable the editing field (or to set it as `readonly`) you need generate `editoptions` which don't contain `disabled` property (or `readonly` property) at all.